# If Var on Storage dont show tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i want my App to check if a variable "myAccount" is on native storage to show or not Tabs, i used ionViewCanEnter to check if the variable *myAccount* is present on local Storage, if its not *isConnected* will be set to false, if its *isConnected* will be set to true
here's my code:

**tabs.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { MyaccountPage } from '../myaccount/myaccount';
/**
 * Generated class for the TabsPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {
  public isConnected: Boolean= true;

  homeRoot = HomePage;
  myAccountRoot = MyaccountPage;
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {

  }



  ionViewCanEnter(){
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('myAccount')
    .then(
       //data => this.isConnected=false,
     // error => this.isConnected=true
      data => this.isConnected=true,
      error => this.isConnected=false
    );
  }
  logout(){
    this.nativeStorage.remove('myAccount');
    this.isConnected=false;
  }

}
```

if *isConnected* is true it will show the tabs with HomePage as selectedIndex with the tabs visible, if its not it will show the HomePage with no Tabs

**tabs.html:**

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" *ngIf="isConnected" class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
  <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot"  tabIcon="home"> </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="myAccountRoot"  tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="myAccountRoot"  tabIcon="chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="logout()"  tabIcon="power"></ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" *ngIf="!isConnected">{{isConnected}}</ion-nav>
```

The probleme is that its not totally working, when *myAccount* is added to storage, the tabs doesnt show up but if i exit the application and relaunch it, they appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used ionViewWillEnter and it worked